# xsl:character-map to replace special characters

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Given an element with a value of:

```
 <xml_element>Distrib = SU &amp; Prem &amp;lt;&amp;gt; 0</xml_element>
```

I need to turn `&amp;lt;` or `&amp;gt;` into `&lt;` or `&gt;` 
because a downstream app requires it in this format throughout the entire XML document.  I would need this for quotes and apostrophes too.  I am tryinging a character-map in XSLT 2.0.

```
<xsl:character-map name="specialchar">
    <xsl:output-character character="&apos;" string="&amp;apos;" />
    <xsl:output-character character="&quot;" string="&amp;quot;" />
    <xsl:output-character character="&gt;" string="&amp;gt;" />
</xsl:character-map>
```

Answer (score 8):

The **[`<xsl:character-map>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps)** instruction can be used to serialize a *single character* to any string. However this problem requires more than one character (an ampersand followed by another character to be replaced.

`<xsl:character-map>` cannot be used to solve such problems.

**Here is a solution to this problem, using the XPath 2.0 `replace()` function:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:value-of select=
    'replace(
        replace(
                replace(., "&amp;lt;", "&lt;"),
                "&amp;gt;",
                "&gt;"
                ),
        "&amp;apos;",
        "&apos;"
        )
    '/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<xml_element>Distrib = SU &amp; &amp;apos;Prem &amp;lt;&amp;gt; 0</xml_element>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<xml_element>Distrib = SU &amp; 'Prem &lt;&gt; 0</xml_element>
```